# Rake cannot load such file cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, rake

I'm trying to setup an application on a ubuntu VPS with rvm installed. The `thin` webserver works fine, but all the rake commands fails with same error message.

```
LoadError: cannot load such file -- cucumber/rake/task
```

I've this on my Rakefile:

```
require 'cucumber/rake/task'
```

I've tried with

```
gem install cucumber
gem install guard-cucumber
gem install cucumber-rails
gem install rake
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Nothing seems to work

```
#which ruby
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby

#which rake
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@search-demo/bin/rake
```

What else could be or how I can debug this?

Comment: maybe the gems are not loaded on production environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the load path printing the `$:` var. check if you have the `cucumber` gem there and if it match the version that you have on your local machine, where I suppose is working.

If the gem path is not there, be sure it is installed with

```
 gem list | grep cucu
```

Also compare versions with your local environment.

Check your Gemfile, make sure you dont have those gems on a `group :development` block or similar, cause you have probably set `RAILS_ENV` in your vps to production.